# Why is this array undefined?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Below is my problem code:

```
var counter = new Counter();
counter.Load("20141211");

--

Counter = function () {
    this.Counters = new Array();
    this.Load = function (date) {
        $.getJSON("http://url", { "Date": date }, function (Count) {
            if (!Count.Error) {
                this.Counters[this.Counters.length] = Count;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The line `this.Counters[this.Counters.length] = Count;` is where `this.Counters` is undefined and I don't understand why as it is defined above.

I would think it got defined when I call `new Counter()`, so it can be used later when I call `counter.Load()`. But it is simply undefined.

If I where to create this as a linear code it would work:

```
var Counters = new Array();
Counters[Counters.length] = Count;
```

Comment: Because `this` is different inside your callback.

Comment: for the record, `this.Counters = []` is faster than using `new Array()`

Comment: If you've written your code like that you'll get a `Counter is not defined` error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you lost context. Add `var self = this;` in top of constructor, and into callback use `self.Counters[self.Counters.length] = Count;`

```
Counter = function () {
    var self = this;
    this.Counters = new Array();
    this.Load = function (date) {
        $.getJSON("http://url", { "Date": date }, function (Count) {
            if (!Count.Error) {
                self.Counters[self.Counters.length] = Count;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer is identical to @Jamiec's answer...

Answer (score 4):

Because scope!

Within the callback of `$.getJSON`, `this` no longer refers to the instance of your object. The easiest way round this is to use another variable (often `self`) to refer to the instance, and use this inside your callback:

```
Counter = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.Counters = new Array();
    self.Load = function (date) {
        $.getJSON("http://url", { "Date": date }, function (Count) {
            if (!Count.Error) {
                self.Counters[self.Counters.length] = Count;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The value of `this` changes when you're in the `.getJSON` callback. So save the value of `this` under a different variable name and use that value when you're in the callback.